# Class from string

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a class named **Klass**, and a class called **Klass2**. Depending on the user's input, I'd like to decide whether I'll call `"hello_world"` on Klass, or Klass2:

```
class Klass
  def self.hello_world
    "Hello World from Klass1!"
  end
end

class Klass2
  def self.hello_world
    "Hello World from Klass2!"
  end
end

input = gets.strip
class_to_use = input
puts class_to_use.send :hello_world
```

The user inputs "Klass2" and the script should say:

> Hello World from Klass2!

Obviously this code doesn't work, since I'm calling `#hello_world` on String, but I'd like to call `#hello_world` on `Klass2`.

How do I *"convert"* the string into a referrence to `Klass2` (or whatever the user might input), or how could I else would I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
puts Object.const_get(class_to_use).hello_world
```

Comment: Is it better to use `Object.const_get`? I've never used it... tks! :]

Answer (score 1):

```
puts eval(class_to_use).hello_world
```

Comment: `eval` is always a bit unsafe and can be avoided by `const_get`. Also, there's no need for using `send`, as we already know that we will call `hello_world` method.

Comment: why is it unsafe? and I removed the `send`... totally missed that. thank you.

Comment: @j: `eval` lets the user run any arbitrary Ruby code.  They could do much more than pick a class.

Comment: Right, sooner or later you'll have a user which will like to hear how class by the name of `system('rm -rf /')` says "hello" to the world... ;)

Comment: @j:  Happy to help.  I always look for other options before resorting to `eval`.  (Ruby has a lot of dynamic programming methods available, for instance.)

Comment: Not only is `eval` insecure, but it's incredibly slow on every Ruby implementation I know of. I don't want to encourage premature optimization, but it's so easy to avoid `eval` in most cases that it's really just wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ActiveSupport loaded (e.g. in a Rails app) you can also use #constantize:

```
class_to_use.constantize.hello_world
```