# What is the name of the pattern where Foo.new("Bar") creates a Bar and sends messages there?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

Our customers order a `Plan`. A plan, contains business-logic, depending on what plan they actually order.

For example (Obviously the reality is a lot more complex, lots of additional differences):

- Plan 1 *creates* one Site
- Plan 2 *creates* one Site, and a Database
- Plan 3 *creates* on Server of type X, one Site and mails the boss.

The way I am thinking to implement this is:

```
class Order
  def initialize(plan_type)
    # for e.g. plan_type = PlanOne, create a new PlanOne
    # Details at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2811300/73673
    @plan = Object.const_get(class_name).new
  end

  def finalize
    @plan.finalize
  end
end

class Plan
 # All shared and common methods and attributes go here.
 # Might be implemented as Module "ActsAsPlan", if a Duck is more appropriate.
end

class PlanOne < Plan
  def finalize
    Site.new.create
  end
end

class PlanTwo < Plan
  def finalize
    Site.new.create
    Database.new.create
  end
end

class PlanThree < Plan
  def finalize
    server = Server.new.create
    site = Site.new.create(:server => server)
    BossMail.new(server, site).deliver
  end
end
```

Used as:

```
Order.new("PlanOne").finalize
Order.new("PlanTwo").finalize 
Order.new("PlanThree").finalize
```

Is this a good pattern for the problem at hand? This will be implemented in Rails. At most there will be four or five plans, it does not need to scale to hundreds of plans.

What is the name of the pattern I am implementing, or what would be the name of a more appropriate pattern? It is Ruby and I am not afraid to pull in a gem, if that simplifies work.

Comment: At least one variable needs to be instance var (e.g. `@plan` instead of `plan`) because it is part of the object state.

Comment: You are right; will fix that, thanks! Though for the matter at hand, this is not that important.

Comment: I modified the comment: Only `plan` is obviously part of Order state. The others might be, it is not so clear - although I suspect that might still be the case

Comment: What is `class_name` in `Order#initialize`?

Comment: AFAIK, creating new resources based on subclass, with no other behaviour to go on for those resources, probably doesn't have a general pattern name. This is basic use of subclasses/polymorphism - what Site and Database later do in this model may match some kind of pattern though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it sounds like Abstract Factory.

Answer (score 2):

To me it sounds like a [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).